# Fire Prism Commands Manually

Tags: c#, .net, command, windows-store-apps, prism

I've setup a windows store app using Prism.  I have a need to use a command to notify the viewmodel of an action, but I cannot use a button in this case.  Is there a way to fire a command defined in a viewmodel from the view, but in an agnostic fashion, so that the view/viewmodel aren't tightly coupled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(command.CanExecute(parameter))
    command.Execute(parameter);
```

Comment: If the command is a DelegateCommand defined in the ViewModel, and I'm trying to fire the command in the view, what is "command", in your example, a reference to?

Comment: You would assign command to the DelegateCommand of the view model. Or just do something like: `myViewModel.MyCommand.Execute(null);`. See - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff654130.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to put calling command in code behind, you can do what Aron suggested.

If you do not like code behind or it is hard to have code behind, like DataTemplate, you should think what condition to trigger the command. If you command is trigger by some event, you can use Prism like below and you also can choose some other triggers built in Prism or write trigger by yourself.

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadCommand}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

If you have more complex logic, you can write a Behavior with a ICommand DependencyProperty. Binds your command on the ViewModel to the DependencyProperty and consume it in your Behavior.